# Getting Job id in do subroutine of Thread::Pool in Perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, threadpool

I am not able to get job id inside do subroutine for Thread::Pool in Perl.
Below is the code.
Can anybody please help me?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Thread::Pool;

sub PrintNumbers( $ )
{
    my $num = shift;
    my $id = Thread::Pool->jobid;
    print "$id => $num\n";
}

my $pool = Thread::Pool->new(
    {
        optimize => 'cpu',
        do => \&PrintNumbers,
        workers => 2,
        maxjobs => 4
    }
);

$pool->job( $_ ) foreach (  1..100 );

$pool->shutdown;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer.

instead of

```
 my $id = Thread::Pool->jobid;
```

add

```
 my $id = threads->tid();
```

And its working correctly..

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you simply restating your original question? If so, that's covered by my answer.

Comment: your answer is correct but this  my $id = Thread::Pool->jobid;  line itself says that it should be called inside thread routine and not where thread is being created. So why its not working? What is the condition for it to work correctly?

Comment: that means i need to store them while adding job and need to access using Thread::Pool->jobid; in the procedure where thread is doing that job?

Comment: The whole point of job ids is to be able to get the result of the right worker. If you don't have store the id, how do you expect to specify which worker you want the result of? Like I said, job ids are useless if the job creator doesn't store them.

Answer (score 0):

Job ids are useless if the job creator doesn't keep them, so they self-destruct when the job creator discards them.

If you need the job ids, you're going to have to save them, and doing so solves your problem.

```
my %job_ids;
$job_ids{$_} = $pool->job($_) for 'a'..'z';
```

Output:

```
1 => a
2 => b
3 => c
...
```